# Formula for Effective Discount Rate of Discount Rate Series

Tags: discount

what is the formula to calculate an effective discount rate of Discount Series? For EX, If Price of Product A is $X and Discount Series is given like 10%,20%,30%,5%,2%. How can we calculate effective discount of this discount series?

https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110703053015AANbTBg

I found something here, but searching for a generalized formula for N number of Discount Series.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle 1-\prod_i(1-d_i)$$ should give you the answer, with the discounts treated as fractions, so for example $10\%$ being $0.1$

Comment: This is not really the issue, but is 0.1 a fraction? (Is 1.0 also a fraction? It can be written as the ratio of numerator and nominator.)

Comment: @denesp To me $0.1$ is a decimal fraction equivalent to $10\%$ and $\frac1{10}$.  Whether $1$ or $100\%$ or $\frac11$ is too hardly matters, as that discount means that the product is free